How to test predicate-based expectation with Swift Testing?
Sometimes, I have to write tests that validate that some value changes eventually. It happens, for example, if I need to deal with unstructured concurrency. Here's an example of such kind of tests in XCTest:
let predicate = NSPredicate { service, _ in
    guard let service = service as? SomeService else {
        return false
    }
    return service.something == expectedValue
}
let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: predicate, object: service)

sut.doSomething(expectedValue)

wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1.0)

How would be possible to write such tests in Testing?

Depending on the structure of your code, you might be able to use a Confirmation. In simple cases, though, what I do is:
while (somethingHasWrongValue) {
    await Task.yield()
}
#expect(somethingHasRightValue)

The last line is, strictly speaking, logically unnecessary, but as a matter of style and clarity I like to pound in that final nail by asserting a direct positive expectation.
This move is so common in my own testing code that I have embodied it in a macro, so I can actually write:
await #while(somethingHasWrongValue)
#expect(somethingHasRightValue)


The thing I don't like about spinning a loop like this is that the test will run for at least 1 minute (the minimum duration you can set with TimeLimitTrait) if the test fails. I'd like to just Task.sleep for a short time before the #expect.

I'm with you, and I intend to modify my macro to include a timeout.

@Sweeper if you like, take a peek at the timeout branch of my macro repo and see what you think; I've added a timeout.

I think WaitError can just be declared as part of the Swift Package. It doesn't need to be inside every closure the macro generates. Is there any reason to indicate the result by throwing errors in the task group? Each task could have just returned a different enum case as the child task result, right? Then you'd just need to consume a single element of the async sequence and check which case it is. Having an error named "success" feels wrong to me :-)

Thx, I'll try it.

Now that I thought more deeply about this, does this actually need to be a macro? It could just be a regular async function taking a @autoclosure and a SourceLocation to help Xcode know where to highlight.

This is perfectly imperfect approach that matches the imperfect code from the question, thank you!

@Sweeper rewrote the timeout implementation a whole different way, without task groups. Thanks for the encouragement!

@lazarevzubov OK my macro is ready for use, so now you get a timeout.
